# answer downvoted without comment

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I don't understand this site.

The answer below was downvoted without comment.

[Separating Apple ID](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317971/separating-apple-id/318006#318006)

I am not a points hound, so am not concerned, but AFAIK my answer, which directly addressed the question by an obviously non-technical user, provided a clear factual answer in non-technical terms. I posted it to provide additional detail, and because I did not feel the other answer would be particularly helpful to the OP.

The other answer was upvoted, and provided a good link to technical information, but did not really answer the question.

Comment: One way to improve your answer would be to *actually* describe step by step how the asker can accomplish the task of splitting Apple IDs. At the moment your answer basically says „it‘s possible but it‘s hard work“.

Comment: Yes - particularly discouraging when a moderator does this.

Answer (score 4):

You nailed the feeling - it’s not really about the points, but that lone -1 stings a bit more than it should.

I still get that feeling and I’ve got so many “fake internet reputation points” it’s not even a fraction of a drop in the bucket. But, the one thing that really makes sense is when I answered this question in a comment quite a few years ago.

Yes - someone, somewhere (and only one someone) clicked one button on the screen. Maybe they were right and your answer was awful, but that’s really not the case almost all of the times.

- search this meta for “not an answer” flag - those are the hardest ones to get right and it almost always means “I don’t like this answer” so people’s opinions on what’s not a good answer can run strong and almost always are about something else - their day, their experience, the words in the post, dissapointment they can’t use that answer.
- Look at some +10 answers which get a badge and aren’t anything special at all. Like this one - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104575/5472
- Look at some 0 point answers that are amazing like these:

  - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/102369/5472 (it was -1 before I searched for 0 point answers by George who is **awesome** at answering)
  - Here’s a gem of an answer - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/59056/5472 ( this user is in my personal hall of fame - so much deep knowledge and a gift for writing just the correct amount of words - no more than needed, always impeccably correct and thouroughly contemplated. )
  - Here’s another fantastic answer with no love from upvoters, but from someone that shows great care and volunteers great knowledge here - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205371/5472

Basically, you’re in good company getting a -1 for an answer that is probably quite useful. It’s hard work to keep up with all the posts and upvote the ones that are useful. I hope anyone that stumbles across this thread is encouraged to vote up good answers, edit those that could be better - edit and fix answers that struggle and be constructive with comments when a -1 is justified.

Comment: There is a certain hostility displayed by some users here on this site. That is enormously discouraging. But I will not complain again about those. – The really strange thing is 0 score accepted answers! Even the accepter does not upvote? How often is this bizarre behaviour observable?

Comment: Quite often @LangLangC - even on sites with larger traffic than ours, there are lots of people that almost never vote up.

Comment: Agreed totally, surely if the answer helped you would upvote?

Comment: Just came across this answer after receiving a small bout of confusing individual downvotes on some historic contributions of mine.  You're right, it _does_ sting, and particularly when one is working hard to _build_ their reputation, it did cross my mind to withdraw and direct my efforts elsewhere.  However, this answer has just provided catharsis for me on the issue, and maybe even acceptance.  As usual, bmike, you're words are wise. +1.